# Hiding blank lines

Tags: css, printing

I have a form for printing with code that looks like this:

```
<p><span style="font-size:18px;"><small>[GUESTADDRESS]<br />
        [GUESTCITY]<br />
        [GUESTCUSTOMQ4]<br />
        [GUESTPOSTCODE]<br />
        [GUESTCOUNTRY]</small></span></p>
        </td>
```

When I want to print, I get a blank line if there is no entry for a particular field.
Is there a way to hide blank lines for printing?

Please keep it simple for me as I am not an expert. I think that this is CSS, but I am not sure!

Comment: basically you wanted not to include blank fields on printing. This would be done while generating the page or custom print codes

Answer (score 0):

if there is no entry for a particular field then you get br tags in one place for eg:

```
[GUESTADDRESS]<br />
<br />
[GUESTCUSTOMQ4]<br />
[GUESTPOSTCODE]<br />
[GUESTCOUNTRY]
```

So, whenever there is no contents for the field, you see multiple breaking line in one place and you can do like this:

```
@media print{
    br~br{display:none;}
}
```

Comment: assumming that no other multiple line-breaks exists in the actual page of print, that will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. There are other mulitple line breaks within the printed page so I think that I need something more targeted. It is within a single cell of a table if that makes a difference. I tried adding the @media.. line but it just shows up as part of the printed document.